# Error de desplegado de dias entre dos fechas en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de desplegar los días entre fechas de entrada y salida conforme al registro de la BD, ya que solo me muestra 21 registros entre ambas fechas y deberían de ser 22 (ya que entre la fecha de entrada 2019-04-07 y la fecha de salida 2019-04-28 son 22 pero solo me arroja los 21 mostrados en el resultado) . A continuación muestro la consulta empleada:

```php
    $sql=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM viaje")
    $aux=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $fechaInicio=strtotime($row['entrada']);
            $fechaFin=strtotime($row['salida']);

            for($i=$fechaInicio; $i<=$fechaFin; $i+=86400)
                {
                    echo    ($aux+=1)." ".$fechas=date("Y-m-d",$i)."<br>";
                }
        }
```

Este es el resultado que me da, solo me muestra 21 registros y deberían de ser 22 faltando la que corresponde al (2019-04-28)

```
    1 2019-04-07
    2 2019-04-08
    3 2019-04-09
    4 2019-04-10
    5 2019-04-11
    6 2019-04-12
    7 2019-04-13
    8 2019-04-14
    9 2019-04-15
    10 2019-04-16
    11 2019-04-17
    12 2019-04-18
    13 2019-04-19
    14 2019-04-20
    15 2019-04-21
    16 2019-04-22
    17 2019-04-23
    18 2019-04-24
    19 2019-04-25
    20 2019-04-26
    21 2019-04-27
```

Esta es mi registro de la Base de Datos

```
     MI BASE DE DATOS

    | -------------- TABLA viaje -------------|
    | id |   entrada   |   salida   | destino | 
    -------------------------------------------
    | 1 |  2019-04-07 | 2019-04-28 |   USA   |
```

Comment: En el primer apartado puse la consulta realizada a la BD de viajes

Comment: el problema es que tu ciclo no cuenta el ultimo día 28

Comment: Asi es pero con fechas de otro mes si me funciona, el detalle solo esta en ese registro, no seria una opcion agregar un dia, ya que afectaria a mis demás registros donde si me muestra los dias que son.

Comment: por que no usas periodo???

Comment: no me queda claro el formato

Comment: año-mes-dia no es el formato de columnas dateo date time.... te recomendaria que guardes en base de datos en el formato adecuado y si requieres invertir el formato para la Vista lo Manenjes con el script php...

Comment: cuando tengas que hacer analisis estadisticos eso te va a penalizar

Comment: a como estoy entendiendo lo que necesitas es que te despliegue los días entre tu fecha de entrada y fecha de salida...

Comment: @Ferns en realidad el quiere las fechas incluyendo los limites, provoca que hay que usar DatePeriod,  DateInterval, DateTime para el rejuego de dias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deberías usar `DatePeriod`,  `DateInterval`, `DateTime`:

***Ejemplo 1:*** imprime las fechas de los limites y las fechas entre el inicio y el fin (22 fechas).

```php
    $sql=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM viaje")
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
            $period = new DatePeriod(
                 new DateTime($row['entrada']),
                 new DateInterval('P1D'),
                 (new DateTime($row['salida']))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))
            );
            foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
                echo ($key+1).' '.$value->format('Y-m-d')."\n";    
            }
    }
```

***Ejemplo 2:*** imprime solo las fechas entre el inicio y el fin (20 fechas).

```php
    $sql=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM viaje")
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
            $period = new DatePeriod(
                 (new DateTime($row['entrada']))->add(new DateInterval('P1D')),
                 new DateInterval('P1D'),
                 new DateTime($row['salida'])
            );
            foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
                echo ($key+1).' '.$value->format('Y-m-d')."\n";    
            }
    }
```

***Ejemplo 3:*** La Otra Forma Orientada a objetos seria:

```php
class dateHandler
{
    public function getPeriodInternal($inicio, $fin)
    {
        $period = new DatePeriod(
            (new DateTime($inicio))->add(new DateInterval('P1D')),
            new DateInterval('P1D'),
            new DateTime($fin)
        );
        return $this->getperiodToArray($period);
    }

    private function getperiodToArray($period)
    {
        //using Index start in 1
        $result = [];
        foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
            $result[($key + 1)] = $value->format('Y-m-d');
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function getPeriodExternal($inicio, $fin)
    {
        $period = new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime($inicio),
            new DateInterval('P1D'),
            (new DateTime($fin))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))
        );
        return $this->getperiodToArray($period);
    }
}


$period = (new dateHandler())->getPeriodInternal('2019-04-07', '2019-04-28');
echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($period);
echo '</pre>';

$period = (new dateHandler())->getPeriodExternal('2019-04-07', '2019-04-28');
echo '<pre>';
echo var_dump($period);
echo '</pre>';
```

Entonces remplazarías de la siguiente forma

```php
    $sql=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM viaje")
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
            $period = (new dateHandler())->getPeriodExternal($row['entrada'], $row['salida']);
            echo '<pre>';
            echo var_dump($period);
            echo '</pre>';

    }
```

***Explicación:***

Un período de fechas permite la iteración sobre un conjunto de fechas y horas, repitiéndose a intervalos regulares durante un período dado.

Adicional a eso hay que hacer un rejuego agregando intervalos al inicio o al final para obtener el resultado que indicas.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php
https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php
https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php

Comment: Si me funcionó, muchas gracias

Comment: De nada hay te agregue como implementarlo en una libreria externa y orientado a objetos...